# Visual Studio 2013 error: invalid drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, visual-studio-2010

In attempting to install Visual studio '13, I'm greeted with

> Setup requires 415MB on C: and 61 MB in:
>
> J:\Visual Studio
>
> *invalid drive.*

The funny thing is that I don't have a J: drive. I've been using D through I drives lately (F, G, H, and I were all 'invisible' and unused drives), but J has never popped up anywhere. I've checked with Disk manager, device manager. I see no indication of the employment of a J drive. Does anyone know what's going on here? 
Or more importantly, how do I direct VS to install on a real drive?

** other important note: i've downloaded and launched the installer from my secondary storage drive, D.
** I am running windows 8.1, intel I7...something

Comment: Your hardware isn't important, so if your not certain of specifics, you might as well take that information out because it isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem specifically with *Agents for Visual Studio 2015*. For me it was because the drive used to be in the system but no longer was, due to changing out some drives. The solution in my case was as follows:

1. Download the [Visual Studio Agents installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48152).
2. At the *Windows Command Prompt* with Admin Rights, browse to the location of the installer downloaded in step 1 and type:

> vstf_testagent.exe /uninstall

3. When the installer shows up, select the *Repair* option (**not** the *Uninstall* option).

Now, I understand that OP's problem was not with *Agents* in this case but with Visual Studio itself. I just wanted to put this info up in case someone had a similar problem with *Agents* or another component of Visual Studio. The error message is essentially the same, as is the installer used to install, repair, or uninstall the components.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the installation file to your primary drive, and try to perform the installation again.

---

Other probable solutions:

1. See this [`kb282183`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282183) for instructions.
2. If nothing right, [`this video`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea0tcHm1kYA)(*How to fix Invalid drive error 1327*) explains how to solve it in an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

## METHOD 1:

**Temporarily remap the invalid drive.** 
Determine the letter of the invalid drive that is causing the installation failure.
Choose Start > All Programs > Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and choose Run as Administrator.

Type

```
    subst Z: "C:\Windows"
```

and press Enter.

Note: The example above shows the letter Z as the drive letter. When you type, replace the Z with the letter of the invalid drive from your install error or log.

Reinstall your Adobe product.

Source: [Link](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/install-error-1327-invalid-drive.html)

## METHOD 2:

Download msiinv.exe from [link](http://www.experimentalspace.com/downloads/msiinv.zip).

Start the command prompt and go to extracted director i.e. "C:\".
Execute the command: 
`C:\msiinv\msiinv.exe -p > c:\list.txt`

Search for the program that you want to uninstall i.e. Visual Studio in our case. Copy its program code which will be like this {90120000-0021-0000-0000-0000545446}

Run this command to remove the unwanted program:
`Msiexec /x {90120000-0021-0000-0000-0000545446}`

Repeat this process if multiple component is found.

Source: [Experimental Space](http://www.experimentalspace.com/index.php/2008/04/error-when-trying-to-install-full-visual-studio-you-must-uninstall-all-the-pre-release-products-in-a-specific-order-before-you-can-continue-with-setup/)

Comment: I don't think people here want to download random programs from random sites. In addition 1/ The linked text refers to a different error (uninstalling pre-release versions of VS 2008) and 2/ your link is to a knitting blog. All in all this is a very poor answer.

Comment: I have given generic answer and I have tested on my PC as well. I have successful remove the Visual Studio 2015 and reinstall it. This answer gives the method to remove any version of visual studio whether it is VS2008 or VS2013. The answer remain the same for all software.

Comment: Now your answer is even worse. Not only did you not address my previous comment, you added another version referring to "Reinstall your Adobe product."